# How to setup inbound email correctly? MX settings?

Tags: email, dns, postfix, dovecot

**Summary**

So I have mostly set up hosting emails. I can send mails from my phone through IMAP with my new server however I never receive any mail. I have tried the following:

```
telnet localhost 2525
ehlo f.com
mail from: eric
rcpt to: eric@f.com
data
Subject: Test
This is a test
.
```

This shows that the email queries correctly however running the following shows 0 emails received:

```
telnet localhost 173
a login user pass
b select inbox

At this point I see no new emails:
0 EXISTS
0 RECENT

c logout
```

However if I do the same but send it to an external email address (like gmail) then it works. This leads me to believe that I simply can't receive incoming emails right now. I have also verified this through sending from a gmail address but it still shows `0 EXISTS`.

**What I think is wrong**

So I have an ISP that does block port 25, and for that reason I use dynu.com to redirect port 25 to port 2525 instead. The outbound traffic is getting redirected correctly as I am able to send emails out so my thought is that my MX record is not setup correctly.

I have my MX setup as follows:
[image]

I just redirect it to the dynu account basically. Is this done correctly? Isn't this basically where e@f.com gets redirected to the dyndns service of dynu then back to my actual server?

**Dynu Settings:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your DNS settings look odd. Normally, given an address of `foo@example.com`, the MX entry of `example.com` should contain the hostname to contact (at port 25) for delivering mail (say, `mail.example.com`). Whoever wants to deliver to `example.com` will then know to do an IP address (`A` record) lookup for `mail.example.com` and then, ultimately, to connect to this IP address (again, at port 25) for opening an SMTP dialog.

You can emulate this process using the following (Linux) console commands:

```
% host -t MX example.com
example.com mail is handled by 10 mail.example.com.

% host -t A mail.example.com.
mail.example.com has address 1.2.3.4

% telnet 1.2.3.4 25
220 mail.example.com ESMTP ...
QUIT
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I changed the Mail server address to: relay.dynu.com. When running your example I get: f.com mail is handled by 10 relay.dynu.com > relay@dynu.com has address 168.235.105.136 (not my IP address)

Comment: I did try changing it so it points to f.dynu.net instead and then when I do host -t f.dynu.net it does show my ipaddress... so I will have to see if that works. I need to wait until my MX change actually goes through

Comment: I am guessing that a connection to `relay.dynu.com` port 25 does not reach your server at port 2525. Most likely dynu.com is not doing what you hoped it would do (give you a hostname that forwards every connection to its port 2525 to your port 25). I would guess that the best service they offer is to host a mail relay for you (accepting all email and then forwarding it on to your server, likely using ETRN instead of SMTP then)

Comment: See my edit to my question. It shows outgoing ports should goto 25, 26, an 2525 so I think it should be doing its job of forwarding emails to port 2525 as far as I can tell..

Comment: The settings you posted are listed as **outgoing** ports, so I am guessing this is for sending mail **from** your computer.

Comment: I think you are correct. I will use their **forwarding** service and see if that works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So I did sign up for dynu's forwarding service, as well as transferring my domain to be with them to try and make it easier but I can't receive emails still.. All it says under the email forward settings is to specify a catch all email address and it gives a primary and secondary MX record. I put those in my DNS forwarding as it says not still never receive.. any suggestions?